# Save HTML File with user inputs in UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview

How can i save the complete HTML file with user inputs in UIWebview . i wanna save the HTML file as is and populate it afterwords

Comment: Could you be more specific about what are you trying to do? As I can understand, you want content of HTML tag inside webView? (let's say get document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML ?)